# C# Optional Arguments - for loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, optional-arguments

I'm in the very early stages of learning C# and have hit a bit of a road block in that I can't wrap my head around some seemingly basic logic! I have the expected output value and just can't seem to marry it up to the input. Could someone step through it line by line and help break it down for me?

```
class Program
{
    static int Pow(int x, int y=2)

    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            result *= x;
        }
        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Pow(6));

        Console.WriteLine(Pow(3, 4));
    }
}
```

The expected output is 36 and 81 respectively and any help anyone has is really appreciated!!

Comment: Why don't you step through it line by line first yourself, and tell us what you learn?

Comment: Running locally, it outputs exactly your expected output. Also as a learner, now is the *best time* to debug programs yourself, and not ask others to do it. Reserve your questions for *specific* problems, rather than saying your program doesn't work.

Comment: What answers are you getting that is different from expected?

Comment: Why don't you tell us precisely what you don't understand? The optional parameter? The multiplication? The for loop? Really you need to search these points by yourself and then ask a more precise question

Comment: http://csharppad.com/gist/cb21dc754c945dfff97b4bb839211aeb It works.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging it yourself should yield the following:

`Pow(6)` runs the method with `x=6`, `y=2`. Before the loop `result` is 1.  During the first iteration, `result` becomes 6.  The second (and last iteration) `result` becomes 36.

`Pow(3,4)` runs the method with `x=3`, `y=4`.  Trying debugging the loop and looking at how `result` changes.

Comment: This is where I'm tripping up I think - why does result become 6?

Comment: @RobP Because it runs `1 * 6` once.